# powershell @' '@ contains @''@ what should I do

Tags: powershell, expression, double-quotes, single-quotes

In powershell, if I use @ "" @, then if the string contains $var, the $var will be parsed, so I can only use @ ', but to my surprise @ 'won't work properly either
[image]

If you just do that, you'll get an error, so that won't work
[image]

Microsoft has told me that I can use two single quotes, but after I use two single quotes, the output is still two single quotes, the first single quote is not escaped, what should I do?
[image]

This is my powershell version. I'm using Windows 10
[image]

I tried using @" but it won't work because the string contains $var. So, I had to use @', Microsoft's bing ai told me I could use """, but it was deceiving me, powershell doesn't have an expression like three double quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use a double quoted here string,   @" and "@.

All you need to do is escape the dollar sign in $var,  with a backtick, as follows.

```
$a = @"

aaa

    `$var = 'I need this'

"@

echo $a
```